# Redirect rule for Apache : Adding www to URL

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, url

I want to add `www` to my URL e.g `example.com.au` . Right now if I type `www.example.com.au` in the browser it gets changed to http://example.com.au . I want it to be http://www.example.com.au .

Below is the redirect rule in the server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What changes needs to be done to the above redirect rule so that `www` is added to the `URL` .

Answer (score 2):

> ### **Canonical Hostnames Description**:
>
> The goal of this rule is to force the use of a particular hostname, in preference to other hostnames which may be used to reach the same site. For example, if you wish to force the use of www.example.com instead of example.com, you might use a variant of the following recipe.
>   Solution:
>
> #### For sites running on a port other than 80
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]
> ```
>
> #### And for a site running on port 80
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
> ```

Reference: [RewriteGuide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: Thanks Neuron for the quick response. But there is a slight edit. The domain name is actually  example.com.au and not example.com