# Adding www to URL : not working

Tags: apache-httpd, url, rewrite

This is further to the redirect query which I posted earlier in this group .

[Redirect rule for Apache : Adding www to URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222684/redirect-rule-for-apache-adding-www-to-url?rq=1)

It is still not working for me , so re-posting the same query . The query was to add `www` to a `URL www.example.com.au`

I tried adding both the rewrite rules one by one as shown below,but still no luck. `www` is getting removed from URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com.au/$1 [L,R]
```

Please suggest further .

Answer (score 2):

```
# Replace 'example.com' with your domain name
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the domain actually ends with   .com.au  . Do I need to add .au in the above rules.

Comment: Please, adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Our webmaster appears to have solved this by having different VirtualHost for the `example.com` and `www.example.com` hostnames; the config at least has much less `mod_rewrite` to deal with...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName actual.example.com
    ServerAlias ...  # any other names for the host here
    DocumentRoot "/some/dir" # required by Apache?
    RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.example.com$1
</VirtualHost>

# main host (actually a CNAME for actual.example.com in DNS,
# but whatever)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ...
```